# How to prevent accidental query execute while only reviewing

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm in SQL Server Management Studio reviewing production queries. I'm a little nervous about having that Execute button enabled at the same time.

Is there a way, in SSMS, I can review my production queries without the risk of accidentally hitting the Execute button (or hitting F5)?

Comment: Don't connect to the instance? Use a different IDE? Disable the F5 hotkey? Check your code before you execute it? Use the Sandbox environment?

Comment: try connecting to a test DB first (which is mainly a backup of your db)

Comment: Well, script the routine, then copy and paste it to your local environment and read the query there.

Comment: comment out your select statement, then if you hot F5, nothing can actually execute. This is the simplest solution, just add your `--` in front of your `select` row.

Comment: This may seem daft, but in one package I had to hit F9 to run code instead of F5 which I got used to doing in VS and SSMS.  F5 did something else, I can't remember what but it was a pain.  I had the top off a pop bottle that fit nicely over the key to stop me pressing it.  Was the only way I could get out of habbit of hitting F5.

Comment: What about creating a login and not giving execute permission, maybe?

Comment: If you have to review queries on the production box then something is a bit off in the process. You should have a test or qa environment with the same queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restricting execution rights might be the best approach, because the DBMS will do a better job at preventing you than your own GUI will.

However in SSMS I think you can accomplish this by removing the keyboard shortcuts for Query Execution. And remove the Execution button from the toolbar. It's probably not 100% though, but.. should get you close to what you want (i reckon).

To disable the button, go to Tools -> Customize. Commands tab, select Toolbar radial. Select SQL Editor from dropdown.

Here you'll see all commands currently in this 'toolbar'. Which includes the Execute command.

[image: Execute Command Location in SSMS Customize]

Similarly, to disable the keyboard shortcuts. You can go to Tools -> Options. In the environment dropdown, select keyboard. This will bring up a menu where you can search for registered commands and their shortcuts. In this case search for Execute, and pick Query.Execute. Here you can find all assigned shortcuts to this command in the dropdown menu below.

[image: Execute Command Location in SSMS Keyboard Shortcuts]

You can re-add the shortcuts and buttons in the same menu.

Comment: Does that also remove it from the right-click menu?

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes script the views as create rather than modify, so if I hit F5 it will fail